# Node email template not working on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, templates

I want to use email templates for different emails (signup, forgot pass etc).
I tried to use node-email-templates but getting nothing while rending email template.

Please see my code below:

```
var path = require('path'),
    templatesDir = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views/mailer'),
    emailTemplates = require('email-templates');

    emailTemplates(templatesDir, function (err, template) {

    // Render a single email with one template
    var locals = {
        username: 'John'
    };

    template('signup', locals, function (err, html, text) {
        console.log(html);
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

I am getting "undefined" for both "html" and "err". Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Does it work if you flip the / to a \ in the path?

Comment: No it doesn't work rather it throws exception.

Comment: Try to use an absolute path. Also you need to escape `\` to make @alex suggestion work.